# Ошибка в Android Studio SDK

Tags: java, android-sdk

[image: Ошибка при создании проекта]

Заново переустанавливал студию, полностью, sdk тоже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переместите `sdk` в каталог,  который не содержит кириллицы.